# A word for how well known something is

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word which describes how well known something is.

An example of the scale I am looking for is :

- Common
- Notable
- Well-Known
- Famous

I've tried the [Thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/familiarity?s=t), but with no luck this time.

**To add a little more context**

The word will be used to describe a scale of how well known a person is between factions, The other scale which is used is Standings (Enemy, Unfriendly, Neutral, Friendly, Ally).

So if standing could be displayed on the X-axis then Y axis would be the word which I am looking for.

Comment: Sample sentence, please.

Comment: I attempted to supply an example through the words that i would you it for, which should suffice. In fact I assumed it would be better than an actual sentence as the word I am looking for `WILL NOT BE USED` in a sentence directly. So Clare and Davo, could you at least attempt to answer the question instead of focusing so much on the rules of the website that you forget to actually read the question. I will try add an example shortly which should supply the required context.

Comment: A scale of, er, popularity could be used in countless ways and in innumerable contexts. You've given no other reason except your 'feeling' for rejecting three words. The purpose of a single-word request is to narrow the nearly endless contexts down to a specific one, so that we don't have to **guess** what you are looking for. For instance, there's the word **notoriety**. It has connotations. We have no idea whether it would be good for you, because you haven't told us anything about the context within which the word will be used. Edit: the edited question seems better.

Comment: I added how i would be using it, is this better?

Comment: You could also greatly improve your question by telling us why "Popularity", "Fame" and "Familiarity" don't work for you.

Comment: Or i could just remove that sentence and stop the endless nonconstructive comment spam.

Comment: I would say the intention is clear in the question - "The word will be used to describe a scale" - so it's a name for a scale, it's not being used in any particular sentence construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with "Familiarity", especially the 1.1 definition:

[Familiarity](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/familiarity)

> NOUN
>
> 1 Close acquaintance with or knowledge of something.
>
> ‘increase customer familiarity with a product’
>
> 1.1 The quality of being well known; recognizability based on long or close association.
>
> ‘the reassuring familiarity of his parents' home’

One could certainly have degrees of familiarity.

Answer (score 2):

Popularity works well as a name for your scale:

***[Popularity](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/popularity)*** (Oxford)

> The state or condition of being liked, admired, or supported by many
>   people. ‘he was at the height of his popularity’

Notice the example includes the phrase: 'at the height of his popularity', popularity is something that can be thought of in degrees, so fits the idea of being measured on a scale of some sort.  You are not simply unpopular or popular, but you can be popular to varying degrees, for example mapping onto the terms in your question: -

> Common - not particularly popular
>
> Notable - somewhat popular
>
> Well known - popular
>
> Famous - at the height of popularity

Answer (score -1):

Regarding somethink which is not an invention, and not somebody :

**Patent** adjective

1. Easily seen through due to a lack of subtlety:
   broad, clear, obvious, plain, unmistakable, unsubtle.
2. Readily seen, perceived, or understood:
   apparent, clear, clear-cut, crystal clear, distinct, evident, manifest,
   noticeable, observable, obvious, plain, pronounced, visible.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/patent