# What is a noun corresponding to "well-known"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm looking for a word that I could use so that the following mean basically the same:

- I want to know how well-known this actor is abroad.
- I want to know the ??? of this actor in other countries.

The following is related, but *the familiarity of this actor* does not sound right to me, and *the popularity of this actor* sounds like that it assumes the actor is known and is talking about how popular. Or am I wrong and either of them fits above?

- [A word for how well known something is](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/386566/427884)

Comment: Why do you want this noun? Your first sentence is much better style than your second, whatever word you put in there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Summary: I think **notability** is the best choice, but I think it is worth exploring why.

In my experience (US English), such words generally have varying connotations that might impact your usage.

The following suggestions from other answers imply the subject is known in a positive context:

- **renown**
- popularity
- **stature**
- **prominence**
- fame
- Q-score
- celebrity status

The plain text words have more to do with public appeal, whereas the bolded words imply a finer quality: perhaps holding an important title, having earned a prestigious award, or having established themselves as a giant in their field.

Conversely, these words imply that the subject is known in a negative context:

- notoriety
- infamy

That leaves these suggestions:

- well-knownness
- reputation
- recognisability
- notability
- awareness
- recognition
- knownness
- visibility

"Well-knownness" and "knownness" feel very informal, like the speaker is intentionally making up a new word.

"Reputation" concerns not merely *whether* a person is known, but what they are known for. Are they renowned/famous or notorious/infamous? If you just want to know how well-known a person is without the qualitative judgment, this isn't the best choice.

"Awareness" and "recognition" are awkward in this sentence structure.

> I want to know the [awareness/recognition] of this actor in other countries.

Here it seems to be talking about what the actor is aware of/recognizes, as opposed to how much others are aware of/recognize the actor. "Recognition" is closer than "awareness", and would probably be understood, but is not the best fit.

"Visibility" technically concerns discoverability. One can be highly visible but not yet well known.

The best fits are "recognisability" and "notability". To my ear, these address strictly how much someone is known, without any positive or negative connotation. "Recognisability" is a bit unwieldy, so I would give preference to "notability".

Notably, this is the word that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Notability) uses to describe the quality of a topic that is worthy of an article.

Comment: Thanks for the summary. Notability (or just well-knownness after all) seems the closest. To me, non-native speaker, *recognizability* sounds like the extent to which people can see it. Is it ever used in the sense of name-recognizability?

Comment: I don't think "fame" necessarily belongs in the positive category. Indeed, googling for a definition of "famous" comes up with "known about by many people", which seems to be exactly what OP wants. I prefer "fame" to "notability", since the latter can refer to whether the person ought to be well known as well as whether they actually are.

Comment: But still a great answer with pros and cons for many options, +1.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Again, this is based on my own personal experience with the connotations. Connotations vary a lot regionally.

Comment: notability is terrrrrrible here. :) I don't see why there are so many upvotes.

Comment: "Notoriety" can also be used in jest in a way that "infamy" can't, and the latter can be used in solemnity where the former cannot. For instance, "the notorious RBG" and the "date which will live in infamy." Swapping these to "the infamous RBG" and the "date which will live in notoriety" significantly changes the tone of each.

Comment: @AndrewRay Good addition. I thought of that as well, but I didn't want to get too bogged down in the particulars, especially since those two weren't in other answers.

Comment: I don't know why we should care about whether an answer has a positive or negative connotation, when answering the question. OP hasn't mentioned anything about it. The title of the question alone would make _notability_ or _prominence_ the best choice, but I think _celebrity status_ is a better choice in the example sentence, because OP's specifically talking about an "actor".

Comment: The connotation matters because it can affect the answer in ways that the asker may not intend. "I want to know the stature of Donald Trump" may result in some saying "he's not particularly influential", due to distaste for his views regardless of how well known he is. "I want to know the notoriety of Gwenyth Paltrow" may result in some saying "she's not particularly notorious here" due to there being little controversy regardless of how well known she is. "I want to know the celebrity status of Charlie Chaplin" may result in some saying "he's not really very famous [posthumously]".

Comment: @listeneva None of these are necessarily bad answers--they're just different, so it's helpful for the asker to be aware of what effect the connotation may have on the answer.

Answer (score 22):

**Renown** can also mean 'level of well-knownness'.

> *renown* [noun]
>
> 1: a state of being widely acclaimed and highly honored [fame]
>
> - *As Nesbit’s wealth and literary celebrity grew, so did the Blands’ renown as hosts.* — [Jessica Winter, The New Yorker, 28 Sep. 2022]

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/renown)]

Comment: Second best answer in letter but possibly best answer in spirit!

Comment: I think the problem with "renown" is the same as "popularity". You wouldn't say Adolf Hitler is a popular or renowned historical figure. "Infamous" would fit there but I think the OP is looking for a more neutral term for "how well known are they, regardless of whether they are liked or disliked". McDonalds is ______ throughout the world.

Answer (score 12):

"Reputation" as mentioned by @ seven is a good fit. Other options are

[Recognisability](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/recognisability) (Wiktionary) The quality of being recognisable.

[Stature](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stature) (Wiktionary) Respect coming from achievement or development.

[Notability](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/notability) (Wiktionary) The quality or state of being notable or eminent

Comment: I was looking for "notability" and missed it at the end of your answer the first time. That's the word I find most idiomatic here (US English).

Comment: More copypasta? Please say why you think each of these answers the question.  We are not a link farm or a quiz size. We expect each answer to be in your own words.

Answer (score 11):

***Popularity*** works as it can mean "popularity level" within a context, just like your example. It is because you are not stating the popularity of someone/something, you *want* to know the popularity of someone/something.

> I want to know the popularity of this actor in other countries.

Here is a different example in a technical context:

> You can see statistics for the whole world, as well as to know the popularity of the query at the country or city level. - [*netpeak.net*](https://netpeak.net/blog/how-to-use-google-trends-seo-guide-for-beginners/)

Other than that, ***well-knownness*** is a word already and it is listed in *OED* with the earliest citation from 1917. The citation from *The Los Angeles Times*, from 1950, provided by *OED* is a relevant usage:

> Sheer ability isn't going to be the only facet. We're going to consider durability, too,..also well-knownness.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly the OED citation is talking about. Does it mean 'we' consider how durable and how well-known it/s/he is, besides ability?

Comment: @sundowner Yes, you got it right.

Comment: +1 upvote. I missed the word "popularity". I knew I was missing something. The word is a good fit to be used with actors.

Comment: Not sure popularity really fits. A person can be very well known but not very popular and popularity can differ among different groups of people.

Answer (score 6):

> reputation

This might work if you meant how "the actor" is **viewed** "in other countries". But this only works for the actor's quality, not the quantity of his being well-known.

- I want to know the *reputation* of this actor in other countries.

Answer (score 6):

A possible noun can be **[prominence](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prominence)** perhaps.

- I want to know the *prominence* of this actor in other countries.

> [The state of being easily seen or well known](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prominence)

Also:

> [The state of being prominent: widely known or eminent](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prominence).

Answer (score 4):

What about **fame**?

It would be more common to say *the actor's fame* rather than *the fame of the actor*, but it's not wrong. [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/fame) has

> *noun*  the condition of being known or recognized by many people

Answer (score 3):

Especially in politics, but also marketing, [**name recognition**.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/name-recognition)

> the extent to which the name of a politician, company, brand, etc. is familiar to the public
> *He already has strong name recognition with voters around Iowa.*

Answer (score 3):

Another option: **visibility**

> “One article creates visibility, which in turn puts you in front of
> other journalists, creating the possibility of more articles and
> visibility.”

― Keith Ferrazzi, Never Eat Alone: And Other Secrets to Success, One Relationship at a Time

Answer (score 2):

This is a little 'inside baseball', but a fairly common measure of this in the entertainment industry is the ***[Q-Score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_Score)***. As the Wiki article says, it's

> a measurement of the familiarity and appeal of a brand, celebrity,
> company, or entertainment product

It's a US thing, though, so I'm not sure it best fills in the blank in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the answers already mentioned, [**awareness**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/awareness) or [**recognition**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/recognition) could work.

Comment: Awareness would seem to imply more how much *they* are aware of other people, rather than how much other people are aware of them.

Comment: **Recognition** is what came to mind for me.

Comment: ***why*** would you suggest these? And where are your links from? That has to be given in plain text, not hidden behind a link. Please review our [Helper Center's guidance on how to reference material written by others](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Answer (score 2):

It's not a single word, but how about *celebrity status*?

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/celebrity-status) classes it as a noun and defines it as follows:

> the prominence of film star, footballer, musician etc who is constantly photographed and written about in tabloids and magazines 
> *There is a downside to this kind of celebrity status.* 
> *He uses his celebrity status to raise money for AIDS research.*

Now, I notice that 'prominence' has been suggested by @Serguei. Although it's used in the definition, 'prominence' has a broader meaning than 'celebrity status', so I believe the latter is closer to the meaning OP's seeking.

The dictionary shows more examples including this one:

> *Despite their global celebrity status, has any of this actually made any real difference?* 
> The Sun (2014)

*I want to know the celebrity status of this actor in other countries.*

Answer (score 1):

1. In wiktionary, '[knownness](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/knownness)' is a word. I'm not sure about the dash but since 'well' is indeed an adjective, you can say say 'well knownness'.
2. In the wiktionary entry for '[famous for being famous](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/famous_for_being_famous)', there's a citation of a quote "a person who is known for his well-knownness" by [Daniel J. Boorstin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_J._Boorstin).

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know the ??? of this actor in other countries.

You are trying to put a square peg into a round hold. The construction you suggest is awkward to use in this context.

I suggest:

I want to know how **well-known** this actor **is** in other countries.

Answer (score 0):

The noun **celebrity** is now most commonly used concretely to mean “a well-known person”, but its original abstract meaning, as the state or degree of being well known, remains.